# Avoid duplicate entries tagged with multiple categories

Tags: channel-entries, categories

Let's say I have entries tagged with multiples categories, for example `category_id="1"` and `category_id="2"`.

Then when I do:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="1" orderby="date" status="open"}
    {categories}
    <span>{category_id}</span>
    <h5><a href="{site_url}news/category/{category_url_title}/{url_title}">{title}</a></h5>
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I get the following result:

```
1
My entry title
2
My entry title
1
Another entry
2
Another entry
```

Why is that? How can I avoid this? If I ask specifically for `category_id="1"` in my `{exp:channel:entries}` parameter, I should get only entries belonging to said category.

Thanks in advance for your help.

FYI: EE version is v2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is a bit strange here, specifically the `{categories}{/categories}` tag pair wrapping everything.

Could you try the following and see if it works ?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="1" orderby="date" status="open"}

    <h5>{title} - {categories}{category_id}{/categories}</h5>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If that works, then that's the problem.

Going back to your original code, I see another problem you are going to face if you structure your URLs like this: if an entry belongs to more than one category, you are going to have a problem constructing your URLs as you are doing here. If you can, working with url segments is probably a safer route here.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

You were right about the URL structure. As you suggested, I modified it using `last_segment`: `<a href="{site_url}news/category/{last_segment}/{url_title}">{title}</a>`

Comment: Yep, if you have your current category as last_segment, that would work IMHO